# Cosine and Sine of Sums

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

What's a good way to simplify $\sin( \sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i)$ as the product and sum of $\sin(x_i)$ and $\cos(x_i)$ alone? And the same for $\cos( \sum\nolimits_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i)$?

Comment: We need some information about the $x_i$. In "most" cases we will not even get convergence. The natural tool is the fact that $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.

Comment: What about for a finite sum?

Comment: Use the deMoivre formula as I suggested. So imagine multiplying out $(\cos x_1+i\sin x_1)(\cos x_2+i\sin x_2)\dots$.

Answer (score 2):

If the series $S = \sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j$ converges, then 
$$\cos(S) + i \sin(S) = \exp(i S) = \prod_{j=1}^\infty \exp(i x_j) = \prod_{j=1}^\infty (\cos(x_j) + i \sin(x_j))$$
the infinite product converging as well.

EDIT: In the finite case,
$\cos\left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j\right)$ is the sum of 
$(-1)^{|S|/2} \left(\prod_{j \notin S} \cos(x_j)\right) \left(\prod_{j \in S} \sin(x_j)\right)$ over all subsets $S$ of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ with even cardinality, where $|S|$ is the cardinality of $S$.
For example, in the case $n=4$ these subsets are $\emptyset$, six pairs, and $\{1,2,3,4\}$, so that
$$\cos(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4) = \cos(x_1)\cos(x_1)\cos(x_3)\cos(x_4) -
\cos(x_1)\cos(x_2)\sin(x_3)\sin(x_4) - \ldots - \cos(x_3)\cos(x_4)\sin(x_1)\sin(x_2) + \sin(x_1)\sin(x_2)\sin(x_3)\sin(x_4)$$

Similarly $\sin\left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j\right)$ is the sum of $(-1)^{(|S|-1)/2} \left(\prod_{j \notin S} \cos(x_j)\right) \left(\prod_{j \in S} \sin(x_j)\right)$ over all subsets $S$ of odd cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suppose that you are after $\cos \left( \sum_{k=0}^n x_k \right)$. Then, we have:

$$\cos \left( \sum_{k=0}^n x_k \right) = \Re \left( e^{i \sum_{k=0}^n x_k } \right) = \Re \left( \prod_{k=0}^n e^{i x_k} \right) $$

I don't see how this could be developed any further.

But I think that $\cos \left( \sum_{k=0}^n x_k \right)$ is generally easier to compute than any other formulas you might get (say by repeatedly applying $\cos(x+y) = \cos \cos - \sin \sin$).