# General duplication formula $\sin\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right),~\cos\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right),~~and ~~\tan\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, contest-math, self-learning

Is there a known general duplication  formula for function $\sin$ and $\cos$ and $\tan$?
 I mean give an arbitrary family of real numbers $(x_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ do we know formula for $$\sin\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right),~~~\cos\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right),~~~~and ~~~\tan\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)$$

> The case $n=2$ is pretty well know but using induction for $n=3$ is getting messy already.

Now some attempt of generalization for $$\sin\left(nx\right)~~~~\text{and} ~~~~\cos\left(nx\right).$$ can be found [here](http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/geometrytrigequivcos3xetc.aspx).

Comment: You can make use of $\cos\sum x_j+i\sin\sum x_j)=\prod(\cos x_j+i\sin x_j)$.

Comment: A related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356891/cosine-and-sine-of-sums

Comment: @drhab that is an incredibly improvement thanks. I haven't though about that.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771838/asymmetric-roles-that-are-symmetric-in-every-instance